# Site specific web browser for websites/apps in strict office environments

Tags: browser

As we all, grappling with cross browser issues can be a big task, in particular making fancy modern sites look good and work well in older versions of Internet Explorer can be a difficult task. For general users it's not too bad, many now use something up-to-date but this often isn't the case for office users.

We've developed a few sites that require administration by office users running IE8, or sometimes even IE7 (I think the market share where I live is higher than average for corporate users).

To circumvent this in the past I used Mozilla Prism https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/prism/ and compiled an .exe to run it (just a converted .bat file), but Prism and it's 'successor' Chromeless have both been discontinued and development is inactive. Both of these allowed me to use Gecko not IE and seemed to keep IT departments happy, most would allow it to be run on the users machine. I've looked at Sencha ION too, but it's too tightly linked to their frameworks.

As neither of these are in active development I'd rather not use them. Are there any current projects or relatively simple ways to build a custom web browser that can be locked to a specific URL, i.e. www.example.com/administration

I don't mind if it's running Gecko or Webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settled on [QT Webkit](http://qt-project.org/) for the time being as it seems to have the most up-to-date Webkit version.

Comment: Did you write a small app for this? Do you mind sharing the code?

Comment: @AmanicA I can share it with you, but if I'm honest what I created isn't great. I edited one of the example projects and didn't fully understand it - it's a bit hacked together. I think that http://www.tidesdk.org/ might be a better option, but when posting my question it wasn't ready, however a new version has just been released. TideSDK is focused around the browser and web technologies.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been searching all night. TideSDK looks cool.